# How does one get top and bottom bar on Adobe Reader app with recent documents button etc.?

Tags: user-interface, adobe-reader

Adobe Reader has top and bottom bars which shows home/recent, navigation document buttons, navigation bar other "widgets". It looks like this:

[image: http://download.chip.eu/ii/3227919641_875d29982d.jpg]

The problem is that I do not know how to open it: menu buttons shows useless settings and info button bar. I tried various gestures - it showed only menu or selected the text. However after random swiping, clicking bar popped out. What is the gesture that should open bar?
I am using ICS - Android 4.0.3 on LG phone without hardware search button. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just *tap* the document you're reading. (Note, not a *long-tap*; that opens a different menu.)

From page 5 of "Getting Started with Adobe Reader.pdf" (which downloads with the app):

> **My PDF documents are in Adobe Reader. Now what do I do?**
>
> Tap the middle of the screen once to reveal the toolbars. After a few moments, they disappear until you tap again.

Comment: And, yeah, not exactly intuitive. Why not use the overflow menu like every other Android app?